# How will be the Memory allocation for the union which contains the pointer inside

Tags: c, unions

```
union
{
  unsigned char* pUc;
  unsigned long* pUl;
  unsigned short* pUs;
} up;
```

How will be the Memory allocation for the up(union)

Comment: Didn't make some 'printf ("%d\n", sizeof(type *));' came to mind before asking?

Answer (score 3):

Pointers to integer types are all the same size, so the union will take up enough memory to contain a single pointer. How big this is depends on your platform.

Comment: -1: [the Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says all those pointers `"need not have the same
representation or alignment requirements."` (6.2.5/27)

Answer (score 0):

The guaranteed way to know how many bytes the object `up` needs is to use `sizeof up`: remember there may be padding bytes in the object.

If you want to know how many bits, use `CHAR_BIT * sizeof up`: remember there may be padding bits in the object.